# PHP - Codeigniter radio buttons

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, radio-button

Im using `Codeigniter` - I am displaying radio buttons like so :

```
<fieldset>

<legend>Part Time / Full Time:</legend><br>
<input type="radio" name="time" id="radfull" value="fulltime"> Full Time<br/>
<input type="radio" name="time" id="radpart" value="parttime"> Part Time

</fieldset>
```

Which works fine, they display.
Here is the code in the model.

```
'time'=>$this->input->post('time'),
```

which also works fine , it saves the choice to the `database`. But how do I get the radio button to populate when the page loads with the choice from the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form helper, which has a function called "set_radio", the very last function on this page;

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

```
<input type="radio" name="time" value="fulltime" <?php echo set_radio('time', 'fulltime'); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="time" value="parttime" <?php echo set_radio('time', 'parttime'); ?> />
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: didnt work. makes the radio buttons disappear 

    <fieldset>
<legend>Part Time / Full Time:</legend><br>
<input type="radio" name="time" id="radfull" value="fulltime" <?php echo set_radio('time', 'fulltime'); ?>> Full Time<br/>
<input type="radio" name="time" id="radpart" value="parttime" <?php echo set_radio('time', 'parttime'); ?>> Part Time

</fieldset>

Comment: do i have to add the TRUE ?

Comment: TRUE will set the radio to be checked by default. It's the same as saying `checked="checked"`

Comment: The 3rd parameter (true or false) lets you set an item as the default

Comment: ok, I dont care about setting a default, I just want the page to load the saved choice from the database, if there is one.

Comment: so if the db value is parttime then the radio button for part time would be selected, same for fulltime

Comment: I just realized you are looking for populating the input(s) with whatever values were already submitted. My apologies - I will update my answer quick.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Craig said, using `set_radio` is what you will need.

**php**

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2" <?php echo set_radio('myradio', '2'); ?> />
```

**Note**
The value of this radio button is "2". Whatever the value is, needs to be the second parameter in set_radio.

Your code would look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Part Time / Full Time:</legend><br>
    <input type="radio" name="time" id="radfull" value="fulltime" <?php echo set_radio('time', 'fulltime'); ?>> Full Time<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="time" id="radpart" value="parttime" <?php echo set_radio('time', 'parttime'); ?>> Part Time
</fieldset>
```

If you want either option checked by default (when the page loads) that is where you would add the third parameter `TRUE` to the corresponding radio.

**ALSO NOTE**
In your controller, you will need to load the `form_validation` library for any of this to work.

**php**

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**
My apologies, I misread the question. What I had above is...before the form is officially/successfully submitted. In your case, the form has already been (successfully) submitted and you want to...edit the form (for lack of better words) - so you need a way of populating the inputs with whatever the user chose.

What I have done in the past - in my view - is just have a ternary operation right on the element.

For example, let's say I am returning a user, and there is a "time" property.

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Part Time / Full Time:</legend><br>
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="fulltime" <? echo($user['time'] === 'fulltime') ? selected="selected" : '';  ?> />
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="parttime" <? echo($user['time'] === 'parttime') ? selected="selected" : ''; ?> />
</fieldset>
```

Maybe that's closer to what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks for the response. yes you understand what im looking for but it didnt work. It makes the page blank.

Comment: There must be an error somewhere. How are you passing the data to your view? For example in my controller I'll have something like `$data['user'] = $this->user_model('get_user');`
Then I can use `echo $user['property'];` in my view.