# Show value taken from database as a radio button

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have created a database and retrieved some values and show them in my view as a text. I want to show these values as radio buttons. How can i do this?

```
<?php 
    foreach ($records as $rec) {


     echo $rec->id."). ";
     echo $rec->question."<br/>";
     echo $rec->ans1."<br/>";
     echo $rec->ans2."<br/>";
     echo $rec->ans3."<br/>";
     echo $rec->ans4."<br/>";

    }
?>
```

Like this i have shown my values in database as texts. How can i show these like radio buttons?

Thank you.

Comment: `echo "<input type='radio' name='somename'>" . $rec->question`

Comment: Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923940/php-codeigniter-radio-buttons

Comment: @aldrin27  thank you.it helped

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
<?php 
foreach ($records as $rec) {


 echo $rec->id."). ";
 echo $rec->question."<br/>";
 echo "<input type='radio' name='question_".$rec->id."' value='ans1_".$rec->id."'>".$rec->ans1."<br/>";
 echo "<input type='radio' name='question_".$rec->id."' value='ans2_".$rec->id."'>".$rec->ans2."<br/>";
 echo "<input type='radio' name='question_".$rec->id."' value='ans3_".$rec->id."'>".$rec->ans3."<br/>";
 echo "<input type='radio' name='question_".$rec->id."' value='ans4_".$rec->id."'>".$rec->ans4."<br/>";

}
?>
```

Comment: so if array is 4 then you got **4*4=16 answers**

Comment: try this own. Defiantly you will be get down-vote. Not me

Comment: If Question and possible 4 answers are in a single DB object, why wud anybody need to loop it again? Ref: Code in question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
    foreach ($records as $rec) {
    ?>
        <input type="radio" name="" value="<?php echo $rec['ans'] ?>"><?php echo $rec['ans'] ?>
    <?php                      
    }
?>
```

> Question should come in another array